# Pushing items to a nested array from an express post request

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Below is the schema for my monthly budgets collection. Each of them is assigned a year and a month. Each budget has a multiple categories and sub-categories within each of them. I have decided to store them in an array.

```js
var {mongoose} = require('../db/mongoose'); 


var mb = new mongoose.Schema({ 
            month: String, 
            categories: [{
                name: String,
                sub_categories: [{
                    name: String,
                    amount: Number
                }]
            }]
}); 

var Monthly_Budgets = mongoose.model('Monthly_Budgets', mb); 

module.exports = {
    Monthly_Budgets
};
```

Below is the post express post request

```js
app.post('/monthlyBudgets', (req, res) => {
            var sub_categories = req.body.categories.sub_categories; 
            var categories = [{
                name : req.body.categories.name,
                sub_categories
            }]
            var budgets = new Monthly_Budgets({
                month : req.body.month,
                year: req.body.year 
            })

            budgets.categories = categories; 

            budgets.save().then((docs) => {
                res.send(docs);
                console.log(docs); 
            }).catch((e) => res.status(404).send(e));
        })
```

When I send the post request from postman, it does not result in an error, but it gives this:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8a3280924c2d0dea15a1df"),
    "month" : "September",
    "year" : 2018,
    "categories" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b8a3280924c2d0dea15a1e0"),
            "sub_categories" : []
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I can't seem to figure out the issue. Please help.

Comment: Hello, I think this is a very broad question. First I think the schema is good enough (if every month has a different set of categories and sub categories). About the post request look about `fetch` API, also for handling the post request, go to the express docs, there is very good documentation about handling requests. If you struggle with anything (after checking out the things I mentioned) please ask another more specific question.